# Django database in Python3

Tags: mysql, django, sqlite, .htaccess, python-3.x

I'm writing a web application using `Python 3.2` & `Django 1.6`. I need a secure database but `Django` doesn't support `mysql` on python 3 so the only choice for me is `sqlite`. I there anyway to secure this kind of database using `.htaacess` or I can try other kind of databases?

Comment: There's no need for a .htaccess file. A sqlite3 database is by no means "more secure" than a MySQL one.

Comment: @dschulz Why? sqlite db doesn't get any username and password and if somebody find it's location he can download it easily!

Comment: But there's absolutely no need to place the database file under an exported directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **sensitive data**: django scripts, databases, logs, ... should **always be outside the root web folder** so there is no possible access from the web. Using an `.htaccess` is not the good way of approaching the problem security-wise.

If you *REALLY* need this, then make a directory rule to disallow the folder containing the sqlite database in your apache sites configuration or add a `.htaccess` file containing the following into the folder where you have your sqlite database:

```
deny from all
```

That should do it. But again, **the above solution is not a good practice**, you should configure your webserver so that the web root is in a `public/` subfolder:

```
[project root]
    [project name]
        [media]
        [static]
        [templates]
        [public]      <= your webserver should point to this directory as root
                         (see below); used in production with collecstatic method
        [data]
            [db]
                mydata.sqlite      <= you could put your sqlite database here, 
                                      available to your django app and unavailable
                                      to web users.
        settings.py
        urls.py
        views.py
    manage.py
```

Apache should be configured so as that your domain, let's say `example.com` has a `DocumentRoot` that points to `[...]/project root/project name/public/` so that all other folders are unavailable from the outside.

Comment: Can you explain your suggestion a bit more?

Comment: I detailed my answer. Ask if you need even more details ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use PyMySQL. Because PyMySQL can import as MySQLdb.

Like this:

```
pip install PyMySQL
```

**add** followed code to site's `__init__.py`

```
import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Comment: Django should use mysql in python not programmer.

Comment: @HamidFzM The MySQLdb does not support python3, and The MySQL connnector for Python3 doesn't work at Django. so I think this is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Django support 4 tipe of Database engine:

- PostgreSQL (http://www.postgresql.org/)
- SQLite 3 (http://www.sqlite.org/)
- MySQL (http://www.mysql.com/)
- Oracle (http://www.oracle.com/)

For the most part , all the engines listed here work just as well with the core Django framework ( the notable exception should be raised to support optional GIS Django , which is much more powerful than with other PostgreSQL database). If you're not tied to a particular legacy system and have the freedom to choose any database backend , we recommend PostgreSQL , which is based on a balance between cost, features , speed and stability.

The setting of the database is a process that takes place in two stages:

First, you must install and configure the database server itself. This process is beyond the scope of this book, but each of the four databases listed here have extensive documentation on its website . ( If you are on a shared hosting , it is very likely that your provider has already set all this for you ) .
Secondly, you need to install the Python library for your particular database backend. This is done through third-party code that allows Python to interact with the database.

If you're just playing with Django and do not want to install a database server, consider using SQLite. SQLite is unique in the list of supported databases that does not require either of the two previous steps. It merely read and write data to a single file on the filesystem and Python versions from 2.5 support it NATIVELY.

Yes I confirm SQL LITE that is supported NATIVELY from 2.5 version PHYTON.

Comment: But these database work on python 2.7 and doesn't configured for python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the support of mysql in python3 and django is not that good. We can use the Mysql connector/Python from the mysql web site: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

We'd better download the platform independent version and install them manually:

```
tar xvf mysql-connector-python-1.1.6.tar.gz

cd mysql-connector-python-1.1.6 

sudo python3 setup.py install
```

And in order to operate in mysql database, we should change the django database setting part this way:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'NAME': 'user_data',
    'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
    'USER': 'mysql_user',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'OPTIONS': {
      'autocommit': True,
    },
  }
}
```

Attention: the ENGINE part in configuration should be 'mysql.connector.django', it is different from the original string 'django.db.backends.mysql'.